# Access XP (2002) ADP as a client to SQL Server 2005 crashes on click on a bound Checkbox

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

for a Client we have to use a pretty old-fashioned Version of MS Access (2002 XP).

Now I have the following problem: On a continouus subform bound to a Recordset with a table on my SQL Server 2005 the whole MS Access application crashes whenever someone clicks on a bound Checkbox. The bound field on the SQL Server is of datatype bit.

I googled this issue and found that Access XP is not able to handle the difference between SQL Server  (1 = True and 0 = False) and Access (-1 = True and 0 = False) on Boolean-Values. Thus I should switch the datatype to tinyint because of this bug in Access XP. However this does not solve my problem. The application still crashes. Has someone found a solution to get a bound checkbox running in Access XP ADPs?

Comment: Also tried smallint but the application still crashes on a click on the bound Checkbox :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some experimentation led me to a solution to my problem:

Add a MouseUp-eventhandler to your bound checkbox with the following code:

```
Private Sub MyCheckbox_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

    Me.Recordset!MyField = Not Me.Recordset!MyField

End Sub
```

Now the crash doesn't occur. It seems like this way the assignment of a value is done correctly.

Comment: I find it odd that this would happen, as I've never had any problems with ODBC linked tables where the ODBC driver was able to translate the Access/Jet/ACE boolean TRUE into something SQL Server understood. It just seems weird to me that something so basic as this would have been left unaddressed in ADPs.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the the "triple state" property for the checkbox set to yes\true? I wonder if there could be something going on where the control allows for essentially null (neither checked nor unchecked) but the underlying field does not allow null?

Comment: @Tim Lentine Triple state is set to false. Null-values are no possible explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When you changed the data type did you refresh the links to the tables? Access caches meta data for the tables so it might be out of date. To be 100% sure delete the linked tables and relink them

Comment: The application automatically refreshes all linked tables on startup.

Comment: Does it delete the links and recreate them? Sometimes access does not refresh all the meta data so the only way to be sure is to delete the link and start again

Comment: Tried both our automatic application relink-procedure and a manual relink, but the crash still ocurrs.

Comment: It's an ADP. There really aren't an "linked tables" to refresh.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton You are right. "Linked table" is not the right term in case of an ADP. Actually what I did was to manually connect the ADP to the SQL SERVER.